# How can i remove all edges of a specific path(for example the shortest path between two nodes) in a graph?

Tags: python-3.x, list, graph, networkx, shortest-path

I wanna remove a specific path in my network graph, but I don't know how can I do that...
for example, I have the shortest path between two nodes as a list of nodes(from source node to target node)
for example, this is my shortest path between nodes A(source node) and D(target node) containing the nodes of path:

```
['A','B','C','D']
```

Does anybody know how I can remove this path from the graph??
I tried many ways to do that, but they didn't work ...
I've defined my graph using networkx library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start by creating a list of edges to remove, here called `sp`:

```
sp = []
for i in range(0,len(shortestpath)-1):
    sp.append((shortestpath[i],shortestpath[i+1]))
```

And then remove them using `G.remove_edge`:

```
for u, v in sp:
    G.remove_edge(u, v)
```

Here is the full code with a small example:

```
G = nx.Graph([(0, 1), (0, 3), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)])
shortestpath = (3, 0, 1)
sp = []
for i in range(0,len(shortestpath)-1):
    sp.append((shortestpath[i],shortestpath[i+1]))
for u, v in sp:
    G.remove_edge(u, v)
```

Comment: It helped me! thank you so much for your useful answer!

Comment: Please mark it as the right answer if you believe it to be (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I am new here so I don't know how to work with this site very well !... I accepted it! thanks again.

Comment: No problem ;) if you need any further help.. just ask :))